# Printing Small Numbers Between 1 and 100 in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and this is a simple question but i'm having trouble printing small numbers between 1 and 100. Small numbers are those less than 20 and I want my program to print out "small x" for each small number.

When I run this I'm not getting what I'm suppose to I just get "small x" printed 100 times.

Here's my code:

```
class ExerciseA {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1;
    while ( x  <  100 ) {
        x = x + 1;
        if( x > 20) {
         System.out.println("small x");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want `if ( x < 20 )`

Comment: Java doesn't support [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>` means greater, but you  want lesser. So use `<`. Another thing in your code, 1 would not be printed as it's being incremented before printing. This should be:

```
int x = 0;
while ( x  <  100 ) {
    x++; // shorter than x = x + 1;
    if (x < 20) {
        System.out.println("small x");
       //System.out.println("small " + x); //if want to print like small 1, small 2 etc.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your System.out.println is printing small x since it is using the whole string instead of using the value of variable x.

Also, if you want to print small x for numbers less than 20, you should use x<20.

```
int x = 0;
while ( x  <  100 ) {
    x = x + 1;
    if( x < 20) {
     System.out.println("small " + x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write down such kind of loops in the more matching for-loop style:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (isSmall(i)) {
     System.out.println("small i");
  }
```

using a bit of "re-factoring" by putting the check "is this a small number" into its own method:

```
private boolean isSmall(int i) {
  return i < 20;
}
```

Using such small methods is something that you should get used to as soon as possible - as it helps to "isolate" certain functionality. Another change I made: in computer science, variables for whole numbers are typically called "i,j,k" ... and so on; whereas x, y, ... would be for floating point numbers!

And of course: you got the comparison wrong - if you want numbers smaller than 20, well, than you have to say so ( i **<** 20 ).

Comment: In this case it would be `i <= 100` since the increment happens first in the `while` loop version.